EC2 instance takes some minutes before dns resolution works
I have two ec2 instances in the same VPC, lets call them instance A and B. I'm creating another instance, named C and also creating an entry in the aws load balancer which points to a target group containing C via a hostname.
C has a custom AMI that contains a web application and it immediately becomes reachable from the internet and from instance A after the instance starts running and load balancer rule is created.
The problem is instance B, which takes a good 5 minutes to be able to start resolving address of C. When I curl from B to C, it says "Could not resolve host..." for about 4-5 minutes and after that it becomes reachable without me doing anything.
This causes problems as the service is up and running from the perspective of end users and instance A but not from instance B. It starts to work after a few minutes so there is no permanent problem.
Instance A and B has the same AMI and as far as I see they have a very similar configuration. No advanced/specific network configuration has been made to either. What kind of things can cause this weird behavior?

Maybe something is trying to resolve C too early, which causes a negative entry to be cached for those minutes?  You could try using a DNS tool like dig or drill to get more information about what's going on, or try bypassing the cache to see if that's the issue.  You're looking for a TTL value that decreases to zero, the next query after that will cause the lookup to be performed again and will likely give the correct positive/non-error response.

@SamMason I tried to disable dns cache by editing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and setting Cache=no then restarting sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved . But it had no effect...
